# In Windows, how do I start an elevated cmd.exe or powershell.exe process with UAC prompt AND get access to its STDIN/STDOUT?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, security, uac

I'm writing a Python program where I want to be able to start a UAC elevated powershell.exe/cmd.exe process in "interactive mode" and be able to send commands to the powershell/cmd process, wait for the console to return/flush (not exit), read whatever output there is and then continue sending more commands to the same shell instance.

I need this for a distributed app, so its important that it prompts the user for UAC access via Windows standard UI as opposed to requiring my app to know the users password or something like that. In the end Im looking to achieve the following syntax to interact with the console via Python (Im pasting this here just to give a more clear idea of the requirements, **answers do not need to be python specific**):

```py
c = Console(elevated=True) # A class I'm writing that acts as a wrapper for interacting with the console. UAC Yes/No prompt should appear on screen here, again, its important that it prompts the user & runs on most Windows installations.
c.sendCmd("echo hello")
import time
time.sleep(3)
returnVal = c.sendCmd("echo there", waitForReturn=True)
print(returnVal) # prints "there" to the console
```

I've also made an implementation of this already (for python 3.10), with no UAC (hence my question here on stack as I cant quite seem to figure out how to achieve my question in the title): https://pastebin.com/SUQrcfxq

The only solution I've been able to think of so far that I believe could satisfy all my requirements would be writing a little program that acts as a wrapper for cmd.exe/powershell.exe & uses sockets to forwards stdin/stdout - however atm Im not entirely sure how to implement that.